# Why is my PHP if statement not working correctly?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a comment system and when a new comment comes I will email them.

I created a table in phpMyAdmin called **email_notifications**.

The problem is with this code:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email_notifications WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error())) <= 1) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO email_notifications (email) VALUES ('$email')");
    echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email_notifications WHERE email='$email'"));
} 
else{
    die('EMAIL!');
}
```

That is suppose to prevent more than one of the same email to be in that table.
And right now mysql_num_rows says that there are 7 rows.

So the statment now says:

```
if(7 <= 1) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO email_notifications (email) VALUES ('$email')");
    echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email_notifications WHERE email='$email'"));
}
else{
    die('Can\'t post this email! Sorry.');
}
```

The problem is that it's still inserting the email address into the table but it shouldn't. It should be returning *Can't post this email! Sorry.*

This is probable the weirdest problem I've faced and I can't figure it out :(

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note: instead of writing "_PHP is not reading my if correctly_" you should rather write "_I am not writing `if` for PHP correctly_". No offense, PHP is predictable and is rather mature - you should rather ask a question, whether you have written this condition correctly instead of accusing a programming language.

Comment: But the condition looks correct to me.

Comment: It might but as you admit, you're inexperienced with MySql/PHP and this sort of bug would have come out and been solved a long time ago! Also, look into MySql Count function; it would likely fix this.

Comment: I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing your variables in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evidently, the value of `mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email_notifications WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error())` is not equal to 7, and is therefore, less than or equal to 1. This is the reason why your if statement is not running as expected.

Also, please format your code a bit better:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email_notifications WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());

$numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($query);

echo $numberOfRows; //check the number of rows.

if($numberOfRows <= 1) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO email_notifications (email) VALUES ('$email')");
    $query_ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email_notifications WHERE email='$email'");
    var_dump(mysql_num_rows($query_));
} 
else{
    die('EMAIL!');
}
```

Comment: I would change the whole thing to use SELECT COUNT(*) or SELECT COUNT(email) to reduce the amount of throwaway network traffic.

Comment: Max, its still adding more than one of the same email to the table :/

Comment: What are you getting from the `echo $numberOfRows` output?

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with just adding a key?

```
ALTER TABLE email_notifications ADD UNIQUE email (email)
```

Never have to worry about duplicates again.

Comment: I forgot to mention, im new to php and mysql. So what do I do with that Alter table thing? Just add it in the mysql_query?

Comment: Run that once (for example in phpMyAdmin). It'll probably fail saying there's a duplicate record. Either delete any duplicates manually, or `TRUNCATE` the table and start over.

Comment: no no, you need to do that from the MySQL console, it's a one time thing that needs to be done.

Comment: @RussC Or you can do it right in phpMyAdmin under the "SQL" tab.

Comment: Indeed :) my MySql is rather rusty though, seems like its all oracle now (for my work)